# need to check all items in string array with if condition

Tags: c#, .net, string

i have got the below code to check whether the login user access to menu item

but if first item fails the **if** condition it is redirecting to error page, but i need to check second item from that string array with if condition even the first item fails the if condition ...

please find the below given code for test..

```
var count = 0;
string[] strPageId = PageId.Split(';');


foreach (string menuPageId in strPageId)
{
       if (objDALookup.IsPageVisible(PageType,Int32.Parse(menuPageId), role, AcctId) == false)
       {
           Session["ErrorInfo"] = "Access denied, please contact system administrator.";
           new Lib.Utils.Log().logInfo("FORCE_ACCESS", strUser + " tried to access PageId:" + PageId + " PageType:" + PageType);
           Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ACCESS_DENIED_URL"], true);
       }
       else
       {
            count++;
            if (count == strPageId.Length) break;

       }
 }
```

Comment: So do you want to check all items or just next item in the list after the failing one?

Comment: all items in the same list ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make condition something like this by figuring out condition in loop and executing the action outside loop once it is decided.

```
bool access = false;
foreach (string menuPageId in strPageId)
{    
   if (objDALookup.IsPageVisible(PageType,Int32.Parse(menuPageId), role, AcctId) == true)
   {
        access = true; 
        break;
   }
}

if(!access)
{

    Session["ErrorInfo"] = "Access denied, please contact system administrator.";
           new Lib.Utils.Log().logInfo("FORCE_ACCESS", strUser + " tried to access PageId:" + PageId + " PageType:" + PageType);

     Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ACCESS_DENIED_URL"], true);
}
```

OR

You can use linq

```
bool access = strPageId.Any(s=> objDALookup.IsPageVisible(PageType,Int32.Parse(menuPageId), role, AcctId) == true);

if(!access)
{

}
```

Comment: Putting not with access bool result would do when access is not to any of tab.